# Changing A Variable in PHP

Tags: php, variables

I have a textbox on a webpage and would like to update the variable sitename to the textbox value. The sitename variable is already set to something in my configuration.php file, but would like this to be 'overridden'. At the moment, it remembers it on that page but as soon as you click on a new page, it goes back to what was set in the configuration.php file.

My webpage (May help?)

```
if(isset($_POST['sitename']))
{   
    $config->sitename = $_POST['sitename'];
}
else
{
$error = "You can't leave the sitename field blank.";
}
```

Any ideas? Couldn't find anything anywhere :(

Comment: your config object needs to be session persistent to remember it. Why not use SESSION variable and store it in session ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is stateless, every-time it runs it reloads all configurations, when u set your `$config->sitename` variable you are changing it only for that specific execution, any other execution will go back to using your configuration.php file.

The only way to do this is to change the source of your configurations, in this case your configuration.php file, but this might be very very bad as it allows a user to write to a executable file.

Id suggest using a local text file or a database.

If you chose to save these configs on a file you could save them as JSON, Yaml or plain config text.

PS: Note that if you want to change the configuration only for a single user then a user session is a better and easier approach.

Comment: Ok, I just wanted something that allows someone to change something in a backend interface and then show those settings frontend. A database is probably the easiest route. Thanks.